# Android Gimbal Push notification

Tags: android

I am using Gimbal for my application. Gimbal searches location of my device, but is not sending a push notification.
Logcat prints the following error:

> [PushTokenJob] Google Play Services not available - unable to register for push

My code is:

```
  PlaceManager.getInstance().startMonitoring();
               CommunicationManager.getInstance().startReceivingCommunications();

 // Setup Push Communication

 String gcmSenderId = "479334007363"; // <--- SET THIS STRING TO YOUR PUSH SENDER ID HERE (Google API project #) ##

registerForPush(gcmSenderId);
```

In registerForPush method I called Gimbal's method for push notification:

```
        Gimbal.registerForPush(gcmSenderId);
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable push notifications the project requires the google-play-services library project provided by Google. Follow the instructions here http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html to setup Google Play Services for your project. Once you have this set up you should no longer see the "[PushTokenJob] Google Play Services not available - unable to register for push" error. If you are using Eclipse you have to restart before it picks up the changes.

To test this in the sample application that gets shipped as part of Gimbal SDK, make sure you uncomment the  tag in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> —>
```

In the future, you can get faster answers from Gimbal by logging into your Gimbal account at https://manager.gimbal.com and the clicking on [Support] > [Submit a Request] to open a support ticket with our dedicated support team.